# Maven2 - POM configure issue in Windows

Tags: windows, maven-2, pom.xml, tomcat

I'm trying to configure maven in my windows machine. My (webappDirectory)  pom.xml is as follows

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <webappDirectory>C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.32-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\webapps\myapp</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I'm using apache-tomcat and its working fine. But when i do a clean build and run, nothing goes to my webapp directory. I guess its something to do with the path

I'm a newbie to maven

can anyone help thanks in advance

cheers

thusitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webappDirectory is the directory where the war file will be created. But that should NOT be a directory where a tomcat is installed (hot deployment). I suggest to use the [convention of the maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html). if you like to deploy the war to a tomcat you can take a look to [cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) or you can use a jetty container for testing. Furthermore you should take a deep look into the Books about Maven for example: [Maven by Example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html). Nevertheless if you think about your setup. This setup works only on your computer and this build not portable to an other machine or less portable to an other operating system (like Unix). In other word don't put the webDirectory in your configuration leave it to the default. I missed to say that you are using an old version of the maven-war-plugin the most up-to-date version is 2.1.1.